# Update statement clarification

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm extremely new to "updating" databases as I've only ever wrote queries as select statements.

I have a record i need to delete or change from the database.  How would I go about doing that?  Lets take updating a column first.

I want to update the "Customer" table and the "SNumber" column where the "TicketNum" Column is "123" Right now "SNumber" for that record is blank, and i'd like it to be "115"

I was thinking:

```
update Customer
set snumber = '115'
where ticketnum = '123'
```

Obviously I do not want to run this query with fear of messing up the database.

The second part of this is how would I delete the record all together?

Thanks

Comment: Create a backup of the database, or at least a copy of the table.  Run this: SELECT * INTO Customer_temp FROM Customer.  You'll have a full copy of the table.

Comment: If you're really nervous about applying updates, you might want to consider turning on [implicit transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188317(v=sql.105).aspx) for the time being. That way, the only way your changes become permanent is if you `COMMIT`. If it all goes wrong, you can `ROLLBACK` (or close your connection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is correct.

remember you can update and then issue a ROLLBACk if you need to undo it.

delete is similar:

```
delete customer where ticketnum = 123;
```

Comment: let me comment that the table customer - probably should not have a column ticketnum... this seems like a design problem

Comment: I just made up column names.  Can you explain the ROLLBACK?

Comment: ROLLBACK says - undo my last changes, COMMIT says apply my last changes.

Comment: @Shmewnix - `ROLLBACK` and `COMMIT` are only available if you have an open transaction. By *default*, SQL Server will automatically `COMMIT` if the statement you've given it executes without error, unless you've opened an explicit transaction.

Answer (score 2):

If you are new I recommend searching about CRUD operations using tSQL. For example:

- [Update on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [Delete on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174018%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

As for your question. You will not mess up the database with that UPDATE clause, it is correct.

To delete the row just use:

```
DELETE FROM Customer
 WHERE ticketnum = '123'
```

`ROLLBACK`, as recommended on other answer, helps to roll back an action (transaction) that was incorrect or erroneus or just because some data is not correct. See [MSDN for ROLLBACK sintax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms181299%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

This is closely related to **[TRANSACTIONS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174377.aspx)** concept.

Answer (score 0):

The general form of update in SQL is
    UPDATE table
    SET column = expression
    WHERE predicates;

and an example would be
    UPDATE suppliers
    SET description = 'gorilla glass', product = 'screens'
    WHERE name = 'corning';

As other posters have noted, your SQL update is correct.